# How to create multiple preprocessor constants in ASP.NET Page Directive?

Tags: asp.net

It is possible to create a constant like this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx

```
<%@ Page CompilerOptions="/d:QUUX" %>
```

How to create multiple constants ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the `Csc.exe /define:` (or `vbc.exe` if you're using VB, I don't discriminate!)
The `/d:` is just short for `/define:` in either case.

To add multiple constants, just slap a comma in there:

```
<%@ Page CompilerOptions="/d:QUUX,QUUX2,BOB,LITTLETIMMY,MYFOOTHURTS" %>
```